# S3 bucket is not removed by CDK destroy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

For example, my CDK project has S3 bucket, IAM role, and Lambda function.

```
$ cdk bootstrap
$ cdk deploy
```

This creates an S3 bucket, IAM role, and Lambda function.

```
$ cdk destroy
```

It removes the IAM role and Lambda function but the S3 bucket is retained.

Of course, the S3 bucket is empty.

Is this the correct behavior? if so, which resources will be retained other than S3 buckets?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-s3-readme.html#bucket-deletion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bucket is retained due to its RetentionPolicy. From the CDK documentation on [RetentionPolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/aws-cdk-lib.RemovalPolicy.html):

> The removal policy controls what happens to the resource if it stops
> being managed by CloudFormation.

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| DESTROY | This is the default removal policy. |
| RETAIN | This uses the 'Retain' DeletionPolicy, which will cause the resource to be retained in the account, but orphaned from the stack. |
| SNAPSHOT | This retention policy deletes the resource, but saves a snapshot of its data before deleting, so that it can be re-created later. |

Regarding your question on which resources will be retained:

> Many stateful resources in the AWS Construct Library will accept a removalPolicy as a property, typically defaulting it to RETAIN.

Typically, this includes resources like S3 Buckets, Database resources, etc.

From AWS CDK documentation for [S3 Buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3.Bucket.html#removalpolicy):

> removalPolicy?
>
> Type: RemovalPolicy (optional, default: The bucket will be orphaned.)

The [overview page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2//docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3-readme.html#bucket-deletion) also has more details.

Comment: Thank you very much clear explanatino!! I set `RemovalPolicy.DESTROY` for my `S3 bucket`. `cdk destroy` remove the bucket!!

Answer (score 0):

In case you plan to put stuff in your S3 bucket, you may want to add a `auto_delete_objects` set to `True` at the creation, otherwise the bucket will stay.